# Swift Xcode auto layout constraints only target iphone 6 plus and ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

The auto layout "picker" looks like the image bellow:

[image: Auto layout]

But what if I only want to target iphone 6 plus and Ipad?

I use the constraints **compact width | any height** in order to only target 3.5 - 4.7" displays.

But what should I use in order to only target iphone 6 plus / ipad? - The **any width | any height** do target them but would that not also overwrite the rules set in **compact width | any height** ?

What I want to do is to increase spacing between three labels when the app runs on a iphone 6 plus or ipad. Also to note, my app only runs in portrait mode if that matters.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't categorize autolayout via device, but rather by class sizes.  This was a HUGE emphasis this year at WWDC due to the new iOS 9 iPad multitasking feature discussed at the keynote.

I recommend trying the following idea for your layout. Note this is just a visual interpretation of what you need to implement in IB.

All three labels have equal width constraint

`|---[first label, maxwidth = x]--[second label]--[third label]---|`

This will make all three labels have the same width and be evenly spaced across.  This approach helps with all class sizes of compact width | compact height, etc.  If you need help finding a way to do even spacing between, trying adding filler views:

`|[uiview][first label, maxwidth = x][uiview][second label][uiview][third label][uiview]|`

Each `[uiview]` in this case will have the same width as well with a background color of clear this way the margining between the labels will be even and these views aren't "seen" but help with autolayout.

If you need help with this auto layout implementation please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me in the right direction. But what I really would like to do is too center the first label between the screen edge and second label. And then center label three in the same way.
|---[first label, maxwidth = x]--[CENTER label]--[third label]---|
Center label is centered X in the middle of the screen. Then center the labels on each side between label CENTER and the screen edge

Comment: |ScreenEDGE---[left label]---[middle label]---[right label]---ScreenEDGE|
So the left lable should be centered between the left edge of the screen and the label in the middle, and the right label should be centered between the right edge of the screen and the middle label

Comment: using ```|[uiview][first label, maxwidth = x][uiview][second label][uiview][third label][uiview]|``` should get you what you're looking for with the first and third labels being centered on their respective sides from center (middle) label, however, if you really want to set it up that way I would recommend doing it with two ```UIView```s that meet up in the center as containers, like so:

```|[      uiview       ][          uiview      ]|```
```|[   [first label    ][  [second label]  ]|```
```|   [middle label - centered to view]|```

But this opens up middle label potentially overlapping.

Comment: This answer does not make any sense.

Comment: @Arcrammer stack views make this easier, but until you can set your base target for iOS 9 this is the type of hack I use.  Let me know if you have other ideas to make this work!